# issue with Twitter API :

Tags: twitter, bots, tweepy

I am getting below error while trying to run the python script to replay a tweet on my account.

```
import tweepy

#Consumer keys and access tokens, used for OAuth
API_KEY = “MY_API_KEY”
API_SECRET_KEY = “MY_API_SECRET_KEY”
ACCESS_TOKEN = “MY_ACCESS_TOKEN”
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = “MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET”

#OAuth process, using the keys and tokens
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_SECRET_KEY)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

#Creation of the actual interface, using authentication
api = tweepy.API(auth)

mentions= api.mentions_timeline()
for mention in mentions:
    print(str(mention.id)+" - "+ mention.text)
    print("heeloo")
```

The main idea is to replay to any one who mention my account using api.mentions_timeline()

but I have issue " 453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
"

also I already upgrade my account to basic 100$ per month
Can anyone help me?Thanks

Comment: You should open a support ticket with X rather than posting here. This is not a support forum